# console.log how to echo strange characters/html entities

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to print out the value of a field without being rendered?

In other words, if I have an html like this:

```
<input value="&apos;" />
```

And I do:

```
console.log( $('input').first().val() );
```

The result will be:

```
'
```

While, what I would like is the result to be:

```
&apos;
```

is it possible?

Please note this is for debugging proposes only.

Comment: `&apos;` within HTML ***means*** `'`. You get the evaluated value, not the source code.

Comment: I don't get 100% the question, but in case you need to get the charCode you can play with `charCodeAt()`.

Comment: I may be wrong but, once the in-memory DOM tree is built, I believe that most browsers discard the original HTML. Even when you think you have it (e.g. `.innerHTML`) it's normally a re-creation. What exactly do you need it for? There're might be a different solution.

Comment: How would you find a blank space break? &nbsp; ? for example on an editable div, that character will make your text to stay on same line, how would you figure out that the issue was the &nbsp; if you cannot echo it ?

Answer (score 3):

The HTML entity is converted to the real character when the HTML is parsed and the DOM is created.

Your JavaScript runs much, much, later than that.

To get the original HTML you would need to make a new HTTP request to fetch the source code of the HTML document, and then write a custom parser (which didn't handle entities) to find the part of the HTML that interested you.